# How to login website with javascript in Python?

Tags: javascript, python-requests

I want to login a website `https://creis.fang.com/`.

My code is:

```
import requests

url = 'https://creis.fang.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'} 
data = {'cnname':'login_id', 'cnpassword':'pass1', 'cntempcode':'pass2', 'cnproductselect':'企业版'}
s = requests.Session()
res = s.post(url = url, data = data, headers = headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

However, it failed.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: "Failed" how, specifically?

Comment: It is different to the page I logged in using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In headers, you need to pass the type of object you are sending...

Try

```
headers={ 'Content-Type':'application/json' }
```

By the way, you should check which is the endpoint that server has for login, *https://creis.fang.com/* is the domain, but the endpoints are unique and you need to know which it is

Comment: Thanks. But it still failed.

Comment: Yes, because you are not calling to the right endpoint. Get the endpoint by doing a login from the browser with the developer tools open, in network tabs, you can check the url that is called when you hit the button login

Comment: Just did it for you, is https://creis.fang.com/login/GetUserType/?r=0.5685585043515144 (now sure what the param r means). Try that or https://creis.fang.com/login

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot login with your code. Can you show me the complete code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a simulate the browser with Selenium:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/